# Else is not running in mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have below query. In this I have yes and no case. 
yes is accessing but else part is not working . Please have a look on this.

```
SELECT SalesChannel.name , count(Transaction.category_id) as count, (case when (Transaction.no_of_units > 0 and Transaction.mop > 0) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Is_Present from outlets Outlet inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id group by SalesChannel.name
```

the output should be as below

```
   KU      Electrical  
Yes   6       2  
No    1       2
```

6 is counter of KU and Yes refers the presence,similarly No is non presence of KU

```
select SalesChannel.name , 
Transaction.category_id, 
count(Transaction.category_id) as count,   
from outlets Outlet inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id group by SalesChannel.name
```

below are three tables which i used
1. transactions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_units` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mop` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `category_id`, `sub_category_id`, `brand_id`, `model_id`, `outlet_id`, `no_of_units`, `mop`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, '2.00'),
(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, '2.00');
```

2.outlets

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `outlets` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `outlets`
--

INSERT INTO `outlets` (`id`, `outlet_code`, `name`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `sale_channel_id`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, '1508', 'Ashok electricals', 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, '1233', 'vinayak electricals', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

3. sale_chennals

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sale_channels` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sale_channels`
--

INSERT INTO `sale_channels` (`id`, `name`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'KU', 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, 'Electricals', 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no data in tables that match for the else condition. Your condition is that "Transaction.no_of_units >0 AND Transaction.mop >0" that is not match in table value of both fields are greater than 0.

Otherwise, else condition works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are aggregating your data so as to get one row per SalesChannel.name. There may be some transaction records that result in 'Yes' and others in 'No' for a SalesChannel.name, so what then is Is_Present supposed to be?

Another issue with your query is that the sale channels are in a table. There are currently two of them, but there could be three or four or thousands sometime. A SQL query doesn't produce a result with a variable number of columns. The columns must be known beforehand. So a possible result could look like this:

```
Name          Yes   No
KU            6     1  
Electrical    2     2
```

because you know you want it to be Yes or No only, no matter how many channels.

The query:

```
select 
  sc.name,
  count(case when t.no_of_units > 0 and t.mop > 0 then 1 end) as yes,
  count(case when t.no_of_units <= 0 or t.mop <= 0 then 1 end) as no
from sale_channels sc
join outlet o on o.sale_channel_id = sc.id
join transactions t on t.outlet_id = o.id;
```

Comment: actually there should group by Transaction.category_id. But when I used category_id grouped by then only one row is coming.please help me out. I want the required output as i given in question part. salechannels are multiple and dynamic.

Comment: Your requested results show a grid of channel names and Yes/No. What does the category have to do with this?

Comment: okay count(Transaction.category_id) as count is showing me how many times i have entered perticular category. yes will show if Transaction.no_of_units > 0 and Transaction.mop > 0 and if its <0 then no.

Comment: I don't understand. You have shown the results you want to see. There is no category in your results, so what "particular category" are you talking of? If you want a particular category, use a where clause. If you want results not per channel, but per category, group by category and show this instead of the channel. If you want both, have both in your select list and group by.

Comment: you just make its else part working please. that is not working. i would love to rate your effort thn plz. you are very expert and experienced in queries. please sort it out.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what else you want. You've got a lot of information now. Study the answers. Think about the results you want to see. Write the query. If you cannot, then study more and write the query later. We are here to help with specific problems, not to teach SQL or to write queries for you. And: Please don't ask the same question a fourth time.